# "new_dollars = dollars + cents / 100" NO CHANGE

Tags: c

In output, `new_dollars` always displays the number of dollars, so I don't know how to solve the problem. Please help me figure out what the problem is.

```
int main(void)
{
    int dollars, cents, count, new_dollars;

    for ( count = 1; count <= 10; ++count){
        printf ("Enter dollars: ");
        scanf ("%i", &dollars);

        printf ("Enter cents: ");
        scanf ("%i", &cents);

        if ( cents >= 100 ){
            cents = cents % 100;
            new_dollars = dollars + cents / 100;
            printf ("%i\n", new_dollars);
            printf ("$%i.%2i\n\n", new_dollars, cents);
        }
        else {        
            printf ("$%i.%2i\n\n", dollars, cents);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cents / 100` is always 0 as it is integer division. Why do you need to add it anyway?

Comment: Reverse order `cents = cents % 100;` and `new_dollars = dollars + cents / 100;`

Comment: Minor: Likely want `"$%i.%02i"` vs. `"$%i.%2i"`  (add `0`)

Comment: When cents are more than 100,  I use "cents / 100" to extract the integer part, and add it to dollars.

Comment: @Nikki `cents` can't be more than 99 after the `%` operation applied to itself. You need to swap it with the line below.

Answer (score 4):

The commenters are right about integer division. Try this, it has the order two lines that do the calculation swapped, so `cents` will still have a useful value when you need it to:

```
int main(void)
{
    int dollars, cents, count, new_dollars;

    for ( count = 1; count <= 10; ++count){
        printf ("Enter dollars: ");
        scanf ("%i", &dollars);

        printf ("Enter cents: ");
        scanf ("%i", &cents);

        if ( cents >= 100 ){
            new_dollars = dollars + cents / 100;
            cents = cents % 100;
            printf ("%i\n", new_dollars);
            printf ("$%i.%2i\n\n", new_dollars, cents);
        }
        else {        
            printf ("$%i.%2i\n\n", dollars, cents);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alastair Brown, I tried the code following your instruction.                  
Enter dollars: 4
Enter cents: 300
7
$7. 0

The output of new_dollars is equal to dollars. No change. It looks like " cents / 100 = 0".

Comment: @Nikki Did you enter `300 7` as the value for cents?

Comment: Note that you should use `%.2i` or `%02i` (or `%.2d`, etc) for the cents to ensure that 1 dollar 2 cents is printed as `1.02` instead of `1. 2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert "int new_dollars" into "float new_dollars";
2. new_dollars = (float) dollars + (float) cents / 100;
3. printf ("$%.2f\n", new_dollars);

Comment: Using `float` may work for this tiny program but it's the wrong way to deal with decimal fractions in general. You were already close if you'll notice my comment above.